# Declarative authorization and mongoid

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization, mongoid

I want to implement declarative authorization with mongoid. But cannot succeeded. It seems like declarative authorization works with ActiveRecord Only. Can I let it work with MOngoid and MongoDB? Any Ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found a fork that could integrate declarative authorization and mongoid. Here is it: 
http://github.com/opusmagnum/declarative_authorization/commit/79ccff34233b2371299c3ff66a18ad37be08d9c6

Comment: In the latest release, this is working.  If you are using Gemfile, make sure to load the git repo as the rubygem repo has not been updated with the latest code: gem 'declarative_authorization', :git => 'https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization.git'

Answer (score 1):

Declarative Authorization is a conceptual model for explaining who has access to data. It's also a ruby plugin that implements this conceptual model.

The plugin probably doesn't apply to MongoDB directly. So you'll need an ActiveRecord provider form Mongo. There is one [here](http://github.com/jimm/activerecord-mongo-adapter). Then you can use the Declarative Authorization plugin with the ActiveRecord provider.